# Console: List index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, indexing, int

I know it's a kinda a dumb question but why is there an index error list index out of range when i run my code?

```
def ilepar(liczba):
    out = 0
    lst = []
    for n in liczba:
        lst.append(int(n))
    for i in lst:
        if i == lst[i + 1]:
            out += 1
        else:
            pass

    return out


print(ilepar('123'))
```

Comment: your error is here. `if i == lst[i + 1]:` When **i** reaches the last index and you added 1, it will go over the range of list. It will print *list index out of range*.

Comment: Why are you using the elements of the list as list indexes? That rarely makes sense.

Comment: Please share the entire error message. What is this code meant to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the call **ilepar('123')**, what happens is:

1) after the first for loop, the list  *lst* is built as *lst = [1,2,3]*. Therefore, *lst* is a list of 3 elements and you can access them with indices 0-2 (lst[0]=1, lst[1]=2, lst[2]=3)

2) in your second for loop, **i** takes each of the values of *lst*. So at the first iteration, *i=1*, then you compare 1 to *lst[1+1]* which is okay because 1+1=2 is a valid index in lst. At the second iteration, *i=2* and you compare it with *lst[2+1]* and this leads to index out of bounds because 3 is not a valid index in lst!

Answer (score 0):

In these two lines:

```py
for i in lst:
    if i == lst[i + 1]:
```

You're using `i` both to refer to the item in the list, and as an index. This is unfortunately incorrect. `for i in lst` assigns `i` to each element in the list.

Even if `i` was an index, `lst[i + 1]` will raise an `IndexError` when you reach the end of the list, since you'd try to index an element that is one greater than the length of the list.

---

There are multiple different ways of dealing with this issue. The best would probably be to use `enumerate()` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate), which gives you both the index and the item:

```py
for index, item in enumerate(lst):
    if index + 1 < len(lst) and item = lst[index + 1]:
        ...
```

You could also use `zip()` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to retrieve pairs of elements from the same list, by using `lst[1:]` to get the "next" element:

```py
for a, b in zip(lst, lst[1:]):
    if a == b:
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

your second `for` loop it is accessing an index grather than length of your list `lst`

if you want to iterate over the `lst` index  you can use:

```
 for i in range(len(lst) -1):
    if lst[i] == lst[i + 1]:
        out += 1
```